# How to catch the changed Object in ember.js observer

Tags: object, ember.js, observers

How to get the changed Object in ember observer?
[My code.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yujuwo/edit?html,js,output)

pushObject set only value, but not set key for new property.

I need an object of this type

`{'key': 'value'}`

Comment: please post your code example here, not a link to it (which my break)

Answer (score 0):

just need to push your objects to your array and that will do it.

```
actions:{
    add: function(){
      var name = "someword_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
      var value = "somevalue_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
      this.get('content').pushObject(name, value);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I need an object of this type `{'key': 'value'}`

Comment: so what you want to do is add property to your object with 'key': 'value'.  You  have to extend() your object instead of  create(). Ember API documentation is your best friend. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_extend